# Python webscraper and parent name issue

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-3.3

I'm trying to retrieve the dates within the div class="ipo-cell-height" as well as the company names such as 2/21/2014 and Sundance Energy Australia. Here is the link to the website http://www.nasdaq.com/markets/ipos/ Here is the html. This block of code contains the second div class="genTable thin floatL" style="width:315px"

```
<div class="genTable thin floatL" style="width:315px">
                <h3 class="table-headtag">Upcoming IPOs</h3>
                <table><tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td><div class="ipo-cell-height">2/21/2014</div></td>
                        <td><div class="ipo-cell-height"><a id="two_column_main_content_rpt_expected_company_0" href="http://www.nasdaq.com/markets/ipos/company/sundance-energy-australia-ltd-672724-74237">SUNDANCE ENERGY AUSTRALIA LTD</a></div></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td><div class="ipo-cell-height">2/14/2014</div></td>
                        <td><div class="ipo-cell-height"><a id="two_column_main_content_rpt_expected_company_1" href="http://www.nasdaq.com/markets/ipos/company/inogen-inc-639597-74090">INOGEN INC</a></div></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td><div class="ipo-cell-height">2/14/2014</div></td>
                        <td><div class="ipo-cell-height"><a id="two_column_main_content_rpt_expected_company_2" href="http://www.nasdaq.com/markets/ipos/company/semler-scientific-inc-920476-73980">SEMLER SCIENTIFIC, INC.</a></div></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td><div class="ipo-cell-height">10/9/2013</div></td>
                        <td><div class="ipo-cell-height"><a id="two_column_main_content_rpt_expected_company_3" href="http://www.nasdaq.com/markets/ipos/company/sfx-entertainment-inc-885264-73081">SFX ENTERTAINMENT, INC</a></div></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody></table>
```

The code I'm using has beautifulsoup and I think it needs something with parent.name or .contents. This code just prints the first 10 contents. I thought I could get something that would use the div class as the parent.name, but the "tbody" line isn't working.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = urlopen("http://www.nasdaq.com/markets/ipos/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
for data in soup.find_all('td') [0:10]: 
     if data.parent.name == "tr":
#      if data.parent.name ==  "tbody": #This line makes it not print anything
            print (data.text)
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach could be to traverse all `<div>` elements with a `class` attribute with value `ipo-cell-height`, check if its text matches a date using a regular expression, and then find next `<div>` element and print the text of both elements.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

html = urlopen("http://www.nasdaq.com/markets/ipos/").read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
for div in soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'ipo-cell-height'}):
    s = div.string
    if re.match(r'\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}$', s): 
        div_next = div.find_next('div')
        print('{} - {}'.format(s, div_next.string))
```

Run it like:

```
python3 script.py
```

That yields:

```
2/21/2014 - SUNDANCE ENERGY AUSTRALIA LTD
2/14/2014 - INOGEN INC
2/14/2014 - SEMLER SCIENTIFIC, INC.
10/9/2013 - SFX ENTERTAINMENT, INC
2/13/2014 - IIM GLOBAL CORP
2/12/2014 - Q2 HOLDINGS, INC.
2/12/2014 - RIMINI STREET, INC.
2/12/2014 - MARY FEED & SUPPLIES, INC.
2/11/2014 - 21ST CENTURY ONCOLOGY HOLDINGS, INC.
2/3/2014 - GRASSMERE ACQUISITION CORP
1/31/2014 - APTALIS HOLDINGS INC.
1/27/2014 - UNITED STATES CURRENCY FUNDS TRUST
1/22/2014 - CHRYSLER GROUP LLC
1/10/2014 - GCT SEMICONDUCTOR INC
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a list of the `div`s based on their css-class, this is using `requests` and `BeautifulSoup3` though:

```
import requests
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

req = requests.get('http://nasdaq.com/markets/ipos')
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content)

ipo_divs = soup.findAll('div', {'class':'genTable thin floatL'})[0]
c = ipo_divs.findAll('div', {'class':'ipo-cell-height'})

ipos = {c[i].text:c[i + 1].text for i in xrange(0, len(c) - 1, 2)}
```